# c++ namespace scoped std set from this pointer in cpp file content is different than when added

Tags: c++

***EDIT:***

Turns out, I was looking in the wrong spot. After fixing typos and adding the rest of the needed code, my example below works fine...

What it was is in my main I was doing a java thing.

bar sample = anotherclass.getBar();

Turned out that was actually creating an entirely separate bar that wasn't being added to the set in the cpp file. While the other class' bar was being added to the set. Then I added the objs to the separate bar. Not the one in the cpp file's set.

Thanks for the help! The comments about the destructors helped a lot because I was able to see there were two and when they were destroyed. I learned a lot about c++ references/instances/values/pointers in this.

***END EDIT***

***ORIGINAL QUESTION***

I'm pretty new to c++ so I may be missing something obvious here. I basically want to keep track of all the instances created of a class but I thought I would keep it confined to just the one cpp file.

I'm not actually getting any errors/exceptions with this code but the results are not what I expect. My actual code is pretty huge so I'm going to try to just give an example.

foo.h

```
#include <set>

namespace foo {
  class obj {
    stuff...
  }
  class bar {
  public:
    bar();
    void add_object(obj ob);
    std::set<obj> obj_set;
    static void print_bars_objs();
  }
}
```

foo.cpp

```
#include <foo.h>

namespace foo {
  std::set<bar*> bars;
}

foo::bar::bar() {
  foo::bars.insert(this);
}

void foo::bar::add_obj(foo::obj ob) {
  obj_set.insert(ob);
}

void foo::bar::print_bars_objs() {
  for (foo::bar* b : foo::bars) {
    log.debug("IT MAKES IT HERE.");
    for (foo::obj o : b->obj_set) {
      log.debug("IT DOES NOT MAKE IT HERE.");
    }
  }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <foo.h>

int main() {
  foo::obj ob;
  ...add some stuff to ob...
  foo::bar ba;
  ba.add_obj(ob);
  log.debug("ba has 1 ob");
  foo::ba.print_bars_objs();
}
```

So in the example above I add an obj to the bar, and the bar pointer gets added to the set in foo.cpp. When I log how big the obj set on the bar is in main after adding, it is 1, as expected. But when I try to loop through the bar set and for each bar loop through the obj set... the obj set is empty.

I may not even be looking in the right spot here. But any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you used a debugger making sure that the objects are part of a Bar object after inserting them? It might be that you are not inserting them right.

Comment: The typo in your last line betrays that this is not what you’re running.  Crystal ball says that you’re calling `print_bars_objs` after your `bar` has been destroyed (and not removed from `bars` because there’s no destructor to do so).

Comment: Please add `foo::bar::~bar() { foo::bars.remove(this); }`

Comment: Ah... destructors. Forgot all about those! Turns out, the bar's destructor isn't being called yet, but the obj's is... (at least in the equivalents of my actual code.) So the bar is still there like the loop says, but the objs are gone... not exactly sure why this would happen but at least I have a direction to go now. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: why is print_objs declared static? I mean everything else is done on instances of bar. I expected ba.print_objs();

Comment: Static was because in my actual code that is a callback sent to a 3rd party library. Turns out... I was looking in the wrong place. After correcting the mistakes in my example above, it actually worked fine... so that got me looking elsewhere. The destructors thing definitely ended up helping me track it down though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of type "obj" needs a `<` operator to order the set. If the `<` 
If the less operator is not defined correctly, you can not iterate over the set with defined results. What is your `<` operator for class obj?

Also, be aware that you are copying the obj instances to the set so that they don't represent the exact originals. Not sure if that mattered to your design or not.

Comment: I actually had the operators overloaded. My example above wasn't the greatest. After I actually fixed the typos and added the rest of the needed code... it worked just fine. However, your comment about the obj instances is pretty close to what my actual problem ended up being! Since this is the only answer and it happened to be close, I'm going to accept it and update my question to point out what my problem actually was. Thanks!